# Resizing a navigation bar to have the same width as the content box

Tags: css, html-table, row, cell

I am trying to add a rectangular image above the main content page (similar to adding a navigation bar). The main content page can be identified by by 'mainContainer' , while the rectangular image can be identified inside 'navBar'. Here's the catch: I want the navigation bar (or rectangular image) to be the same width as the 'mainContainer' or content page. The CSS code part is :

```
#navBar
    {
        background-image:url('images/Register/navbar.jpg');
        opacity:0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80);     
        height:38px;
        border:solid 1px black;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;

    }
```

This is part of the main page coding.

```
<body>      
    <table id="mainContainer" align="center"> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="Register.php" method="post" id="standardsize">
                <table>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="largesize"><img src="images/Register/sign up today.png"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo "$name";?>" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/Register/whats your name.png"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="newuser" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo "$newid";?>""/></td>
                    <td><img src="images/Register/username.png"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="20" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/Register/email.png"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="password" name="newpass" value="" maxlength="20"/></td>
                    <td><img src="images/Register/password.png" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="password" name="verifynewpass" name="verifypass" value="" maxlength="20"/></td>
                    <td><img src="images/Register/retypepassword.png"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <!--Signup submit button-->     
                        <input type="image" src="images/Register/sign up2.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!--AFRICAN PIC-->
            <div class="rigthPanel">


            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I'm sorry you wanted the opposite. I fixed my post below:

If you want a dynamic way of getting the width with Javascript, you can simply call the document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.width or document.getElementById("mainContainer").style.offsetWidth if the first one doesn't work. and setting your navBar's style.width to equal that.

Please note though since you are using a jpg as the navBar, it's gonna look distorted depending on the width of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both `navBar` and `mainContainer` in a `div`, then float the `div` so it expands only enough to contain `mainContainer`.

(A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/USWzB/2/)

The markup:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="navBar">Here's the nav</div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        This content is wider than navBar's, so navBar will have to expand.
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#wrap { float: left; } /* so it is only as wide as mainContainer */
```

This assumes `mainContainer` will always be wider than `navBar`.

Comment: Good work. Now the navigation bar is as wide as the content box. However, both the bar and box are now aligned left because of (float: left;) ...How can I get it to center align, since there is no such thing is float: center; ?

Answer (score 0):

Stealing Matthew's fiddle, you would just have to have a size for the container and then set the margin for left/right to auto.

http://jsfiddle.net/USWzB/3/